# xemacs gdb cleanups.c:264: internal-error: restore_my_cleanups: Assertion '*pmy_chain == SENTINEL_CLEANUP' failed

Tags: gdb, assertions, xemacs, resource-cleanup, sentinel

I tried running GDB, version 7.6.50.20130508-cvs (cygwin-special), on Xemacs version 21.4.21 but I get the following error:

```
/netrel/src/gdb-7.6.50-2/gdb/cleanups.c:264: internal-error: restore_my_cleanups: Assertion '*pmy_chain == SENTINEL_CLEANUP' failed
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable
```

GDB by itself works fine on Cygwin. On the Cygwin terminal, I did:

```
g++ -g -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.cpp
```

to get the executable, and wrote

```
gdb HelloWorld.exe
```

and then

```
r
```

and it worked perfectly. I then did

```
gdb -v
```

and the version turned out to be the same as the gdb used by xemacs, so it seems that the error must be related to the interaction of gdb and xemacs, instead of it being a gdb problem?

I found that some people had the same, or similar, issue:

http://old.nabble.com/-RFA--dangling-cleanup-in-find_frame_funname-td35521450.html

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Also, does anyone know where is the cleanups.c file located? I can't even find the *netrel* folder (it certainly is not located in the / folder in Cygwin).

Answer (score 0):

> instead of it being a gdb problem?

It *is* a GDB problem (internal assert is failing), and you should report it in GDB [bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/) if you can reproduce it with current `HEAD` CVS revision.

> the error must be related to the interaction of gdb and xemacs

Emacs interacts with GDB in [MI mode](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html). But it's still a GDB bug.